# How to pass data in a view to when it is paginated in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

I have several types of data included in a web page.. only one data set is paginated. In the first page all the other data is shown. But when I navigate to the second page of that data set, the other data sets in the page is not shown.. Why this happens in Laravel?

I used paginate function in controller and {{ $variable->links() }} in the view.. how to solve this issue?

Comment: try following code `<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var search_string = "";
   @foreach(Request::all() as $field => $value)
    search_string += "&{{ $field }}={{ $value }}";
   @endforeach
            $.each($('#paginator-parent-element').find('.pagination').find('a'), function(key, element){
                var url = $(element).attr('href').trim();
                $(element).attr('href', url+search_string);
            });
        });
 </script>`, It will get values from Request and append those to URL as get request and will work in the same way on next page

Comment: what should be given as #paginator-parent-element?

Comment: The ID of pagination section